# Auto_arima parameters selection

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out the best parameters of an ARIMA model using auto_arima function like this:

```
stepwise_fit1 = auto_arima(df1['Heaathrow_Passengers'], start_p = 1 , start_q = 1, max_p = 3 , max_q = 3 ,seasonal = False, trace =True)
```

when I call

```
stepwise_fit.summary()
```

I get the following SARIMAX model . I think it is impossible.

Can you help me out of this?

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate, what part of the model is impossible to exist?

Comment: in the output of summary table I am getting a SARIMAX model instead of ARIMA  but no seasonality.